# oracle 11g - what is the way to get the last inserted id of the identity column in oracle 11g database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

What is the best way to get the last inserted id of the identity column in oracle 11g database?

I have tried using the following methods:

- SEQUENCE objects
- manually defining a function/stored procedure for getting the last inserted ID value

But none of these approaches don't seem to be useful for my use case.

Please suggest other methods for the same

Comment: They both seem suitable ways of achieving what you describe. What went wrong with those approaches?

Comment: what specific requirement do you need on your case?

Comment: Please try to build a [MCVE] to better explain your need

Answer (score 0):

Can it help you?

```
SELECT last_number
  FROM user_sequences
 WHERE sequence_name = '<sequence_name>';
```

do you want to get last sequence number or last inserted?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
SELECT MAX(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a very cool feature in which we can use **RETURNING** clause where we can get the last inserted/updated data. Hope below snippet helps.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE avr_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  lv_id PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO AV_TEST VALUES
    (avr_seq.NEXTVAL
    ) RETURNING TEST INTO lv_id;
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_id);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understand well the question, just do this

```
SELECT max(id_column) from your_table;
```